# Return specific portion of a string in specific format that includes a number[]

Tags: regex, typescript

I won't lie, regex is definitely not a strength of mine so hoping to borrow the talent of someone whose it is.

What I need to do is from a string that would look something like this;

`location = "Somewhere" and (Person IN (4,1)) and status in ("Closed")`

I need specifically this portion;

`(Person IN (4,1))`

Wherein the portion of `(4,1)` could include a one-to-many array of number. So for example if I receive;

`location = "Somewhere" and (Person IN (4,1,8,2,10,24,32,15,7)) and status in ("Closed")`

Then the portion I need to extract would be;

`(Person IN (4,1,8,2,10,24,32,15,7))` and the words contained are not case sensitive (eg; Person=person, IN=in) and there may be spaces between the numbers in the number[], but both the string and the number[] will be contained in `(...)` as shown and there may be other random stuff before and after the string contained.

A horrible attempt might be like: `/(?:Person in \()(?:([\/\s"](?:,?)))(?:\))?/gm` but I know obviously that's not what I need, please advise and help a regex amateur lol.

Comment: Where are you using the regex? Programming language/tool?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh right sorry about that. Typescript.

Comment: You could match the parenthesis and the digits `\(Person in \(\d+(?:,\d+)*\)\)` https://regex101.com/r/FQzsSV/1

Comment: Yeah, `\(Person IN \(\d+(?:,\d+)*\)\)` was also what I would suggest at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the opening and closing parenthesis and the comma separated digits in between, where there can be optional whitspace chars surrounding the digits.

```
\(Person in \(\s*\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+\s*)*\)\)
```

- `\(Person in \(` Match `(Person in (`
- `\s*\d+\s*` Match 1+ digits between optional whitespace chars
- `(?:,\s*\d+\s*)*` Optionally repeat matching a comma and 1+ digits between optional whitespace chars
- `\)\)` Match `))`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CGqjHi/1)

An Example in Javascript

```js
const regex = /\(Person in \(\s*\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+\s*)*\)\)/gi;
const str = `location = "Somewhere" and (Person IN (4,1)) and status in ("Closed")

location = "Somewhere" and (Person IN ( 4, 1,8,2, 10,24 ,32,15, 7 )) and status in ("Closed")

location = "Somewhere" and (Person IN ()) and status in ("Closed")

location = "Somewhere" and (Person IN ( 4 )) and status in ("Closed")

`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: So if I wanted to hit in like typescript with say .exec it would be like `/\(Person in \(\s*\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+\s*)*\)\)/gmi`?

Comment: @ChrisW. You don't need the `/m` flag. I have added a JavaScript example. You need the `/g` to get all matches, and the `/i` for a case insensitive match.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously going for `regex` is a good option. But there's a way to achieve this with `substring` and `indexOf` too.

```js
var str = "location = \"Somewhere\" and (Person IN (4,1,8,2,10,24,32,15,7)) and status in (\"Closed\")"

let index1 = str.indexOf("(Person IN");
let index2 = str.substring(index1).indexOf(")");
console.log(str.substring(index1, index1+index2+2))
```

Comment: It misses the trailing the parentheses but that's simple enough to remedy, good option cheers!

Comment: Yup, `+2` instead of a `+1` :)